# How to make a side-scrolling object?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I would like to make a side-scrolling object that is only 200 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall. This side-scrolling object would contain five different objects that, when scrolled into the middle, act as if selected. How could I go about doing this?

I want sort of the same effect that the iPhone home screen has where it latches on to a page when you slide it. Instead of latching on to the pages though, I want it to latch on to my five different objects.

Answer (score 0):

The side-scrolling behavior is achieved with a UIScrollView with `pagingEnabled` set to YES.  Set the scroll view's width to the size of your pages.  Your scroll view delegate can calculate which object is on screen by dividing `contentOffset.x` by the scroll view's width.

If you want to show several items on the screen at once but still page between the individual items--think of the way the iWork apps show multiple documents, for example--there are three steps involved:

1. Set the scroll view's width to the width of the objects, not the width of the screen.
2. Set the scroll view's `clipsToBounds` property to NO so it displays the objects that aren't within the scroll view's frame.
3. Subclass UIScrollView and override `-pointInside:withEvent:` to return YES if the point is within the area you want to respond to touches within.  (For example, if you want to respond to touches within the entire width of the screen, just ignore `x` and make sure `y` is between the top and bottom of the view.)  Use this subclass instead of a standard UIScrollView.